# How to create React Native Module in pure Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, react-native, react-native-native-module, react-native-ui-components

I have a project on React Native that has a bunch of Native Modules and UI Components. The code is mostly written on Swift but it also has Objective-C code for exporting my swift's native classes and methods to React Native because Swift doesn't support C macros, e.g.:

```objectivec
// Calendar.m

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Calendar, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(createEvent:(NSString *)title location:(NSString* )location)

@end
```

```swift
// Calendar.swift

@objc(Calendar)
class Calendar: NSObject {
  
  @objc
  func createEvent(_ title: String, location: String) {
    print(title, location)
  }
}
```

It's inconvenient to manage both Objective-C and Swift method interfaces each time of any modification so is there any approach to eliminate Objective-C code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into React Native macros `RCT_EXTERN_MODULE`, `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD` etc. you can find that they produce additional static methods for React Native to register your module and expose your methods:

```objectivec
#define RCT_EXPORT_MODULE_NO_LOAD(js_name, objc_name)                           \
  RCT_EXTERN void RCTRegisterModule(Class);                                     \
  +(NSString *)moduleName                                                       \
  {                                                                             \
    return @ #js_name;                                                          \
  }                                                                             \
  __attribute__((constructor)) static void RCT_CONCAT(initialize_, objc_name)() \
  {                                                                             \
    RCTRegisterModule([objc_name class]);                                       \
  }

#define _RCT_EXTERN_REMAP_METHOD(js_name, method, is_blocking_synchronous_method)                            \
  +(const RCTMethodInfo *)RCT_CONCAT(__rct_export__, RCT_CONCAT(js_name, RCT_CONCAT(__LINE__, __COUNTER__))) \
  {                                                                                                          \
    static RCTMethodInfo config = {#js_name, #method, is_blocking_synchronous_method};                       \
    return &config;                                                                                          \
  }
```

You can implement these methods in your Swift code:

```swift
import React

class Calendar: NSObject, RCTBridgeModule {
  
  @objc func createEvent(_ title: String, location: String) {
    print(title, location)
  }
  
  @objc static func __rct_export__createEvent() -> UnsafePointer<RCTMethodInfo>? {
    struct Static {
      static let jsName = strdup("createEvent")
      static let objcName = strdup("createEvent:(NSString * _Nonnull)title location:(NSString * _Nonnull)location")
      static var methodInfo = RCTMethodInfo(jsName: jsName, objcName: objcName, isSync: false)
    }
    return withUnsafePointer(to: &Static.methodInfo) {
      $0
    }
  }
  
  @objc class func moduleName() -> String! {
    "\(self)"
  }
}
```

Also you need to register your class manually on app startup to be operable:

```swift
RCTRegisterModule(Calendar.self)
```

**Swift Macro**

As you can see it's possible to write a React Native Module manually in pure Swift but it is not convenient at all. But macro has been started supporting from Swift 5.9 (XCode 15) and you can use [ReactBridge](https://github.com/ikhvorost/ReactBridge) swift macro library for React Native Modules and UI Components. And with this library your code simply becomes to:

```swift
import React
import ReactBridge

@ReactModule
class Calendar: NSObject, RCTBridgeModule {
  
  @ReactMethod
  @objc func createEvent(title: String, location: String) {
    print(title, location)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using expo I have used `Expo Modules API` for native modules before they handle all the nasty objc stuff.

They expect you to write your modules in `Kotlin and Swift` but I believe under the hood they are still just generating all the objc code that you need.

`Expo Modules API` was a great experience especially if you are wanting to write swift code. I wrote a native module without it and felt the objc stuff was hard to keep in sync with the swift code.

https://docs.expo.dev/modules/overview/